# Amazon S3 for Software Delivery

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, software-distribution

I hope someone can help me answer this dilimma I'm having.

I am getting ready to release my new software and its associated content files.  Since the File size for the Full version is Huge, I cant use normal software delivery methods.  The main download is 450MB and then add-on packs at around 250MB for each add-on product.

So I plan to use Amazon S3 Servers to Host and Deliver Software.

- Does anyone have any real-life
  situations on the pro's and cons of
  this method for the  way I want to
  use the system?
- Does Amazon S3 offer Resumable downloads?
- Is there a open source tool that I can use and modify that I can give to my end users to use as a downloader tool, which I can program so that they can download only what they have ordered and also give Expirable download links?
- Is there a commercial tool thats available for the above task?
- I need some advise on how I would automate all this for each user.  Once a customer finalizes an order, I am ok with manually processing som stuff for delivery, but automated is the best.

thanks everyone.
DC